# Angular proxy server configuration with specific routes

Tags: angular, proxy-server

I wanted to configure my proxy server in angular as below :
1> if routes is starting with `/api` redirect to `server1`.
2>if routes starting with /api but has `data-sharing` in it e.g. `/api/share/shareName/data-sharing`, then redirect to `server2`. How such configuration can be made in angular proxy server.
Also , here `shareName` string is variable.
Please help.

Comment: Totally doable, check the documention regarding angular-cli proxy.